# SQLite UPDATE statement updates all row in table

Tags: android, sqlite

When adding a new row to my table, I check if the row already exist, if it does, I update the row else a new row is created. This works fine when I have only one row in my table. But when I add another row and perform the same operation, all the rows in the table are updated.

Am working with these test data:

**Test 1**

```
debtorName: Ann Droid
totalOwed = 200
```

and this is the result:

[image]

When I run the app again with the same test data, I get this result (as expected)
[image]

**Test 2**

```
debtorName: Vera Brown
totalOwed: 700
```

I get the expected result, nothing changes in the first row:
[image]

but when I try to update add a new record for the second row with this test data (or any other)

```
debtorName: Vera Brown
amountOwed: 200
```

this happens:

[image]

I've been trying to figure this out for the past 24 hours with no luck.
This is the update code:

```
public boolean updateRecord(String id,  int newTotalDebt, double newTotalOwed) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    int newTotalDebts = newTotalDebt + getDebtor(id).getTotalDebts();
    double newTotalMoneyOwed = newTotalOwed + getDebtor(id).getTotalAmountOwed();


    contentValues.put(TOTAL_DEBTS, newTotalDebts);
    contentValues.put(TOTAL_OWED, newTotalMoneyOwed);

    return db.update(DEBTOR_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, id, null) > 0;
    //db.close();


}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: can you please post insert code ?

Comment: I **guess** you forgot to specify **which** record to update, by simply adding a **WHERE** clause. Therefore, **all the records** receive the update. Very common mistake...

Comment: Where do I add this `WHERE` clause, when inserting a new record or when updating an existing one?

Comment: In the SQL command: `UPDATE myTable SET ... WHERE name = 'Ann Droid'`. In this case only Ann Droid will receive the update. Feel free to use **bound parameters** for your SQL command.

Comment: Thanks guys. I finally solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it by changing my update code to this:

```
public boolean updateRecord(String id,  int newTotalDebt, double newTotalOwed) {

    String filter = DEBTOR_ID +"= '" +id +"'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    int newTotalDebts = newTotalDebt + getDebtor(id).getTotalDebts();
    double newTotalMoneyOwed = newTotalOwed + getDebtor(id).getTotalAmountOwed();


    contentValues.put(TOTAL_DEBTS, newTotalDebts);
    contentValues.put(TOTAL_OWED, newTotalMoneyOwed);

    return db.update(DEBTOR_TABLE_NAME, contentValues, filter, null) > 0;
    //db.close();


}
```

Answer (score -1):

in your DebtDatabaseHandler class function 
"public boolean updateRecord(String id,  int newTotalDebt, double newTotalOwed)" shows that this function need three arguments one is id which will be primary key so you have to provide id of row which you want to update.